# Unable to EnumerateFiles() from mapped network drive

Tags: c#

I have Oracle VM VirtualBox running Windows 8 inside. It creates share and mounts it as drive e:

`DriveInfo.GetDrives()` does not list that drive but I can list it with WMI `"SELECT * FROM Win32LogicalDisk"` showing `DeviceID=E:` and `ProviderName=\\vboxsrv\w8`

Is there a way to EnumerateFiles() of that share?

I have tried both passing `e:\` and `\\vboxserv\w8` without success, running as administator. I get System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException (for e:) and 'System.IO.IOException. Network name could not be found' (for \vboxsrv\w8).

Explorer can browse it without problem.

It saw it on VMWare and several other machines.

Comment: What error? What code?

Comment: @CoryNelson just System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException. Could not find part of the path 'e:\'

Comment: Does GetFiles() work? OR this error occures only to lazy enumaration?

Comment: @MiloS But you see it through windows explorer?

Comment: @Redwan yes, I wrote that I can browse that mapped drive in explorer without problems